# How do you reset a serial type back to 0 after deleting all rows in a table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I previously asked [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/294727/how-to-auto-increment-a-serial-column-on-update) , and somebody posted a very helpful answer on db fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=871d2b1be9627095a15f07841dcb90b6). This has worked really well for me.  However, now I would like to ask a new (related) question :

Suppose I wipe out all the rows in the table (i.e. in the db fiddle example the apple and orange rows are deleted by doing "delete from fruits where id > 0").  If I insert another fruit like watermelon, the id will start at 4, not 1.  How do I force the id type to reset back to 0, so that  the next insert will have id=1 ?

Comment: Another option is `truncate table fruits restart identity` to remove **all** rows from the table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple (assuming you know the sequence name):

```
SELECT setval('fruits_id_seq', 1, false);
```

Or:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE payments_id_seq RESTART WITH 0;
```

Safe (you don't know the sequence name or are not certain whether the table is empty):

```
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('fruits', 'id')
            , COALESCE(max(id) + 1, 1)
            , false)
FROM   fruits;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=402899ba92090d12b8d57279abed3c59)*

Of course, that's still not safe under concurrent write load - where you shouldn't mess with the sequence like this at all.

See:

- [How to reset Postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23390399/939860)
- [Postgres manually alter sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8750984/939860)
- [How to fix all duplicate key values from sequences?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193568/how-to-fix-all-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint/193577#193577)